# I have hosted my REST API JAX-RS Jersey Java Project in AWS, All API's works well on all service provider networks except Jio (India)

Tags: amazon-web-services

In AWS i have hosted my REST API project all api's works well with all service provider network and wifi networks as well but on jio network, function like GET not working properly (It fetches data but not the very updated data).

Disabled gzip in AWS and in code as well but still the same problem.

API: http://palmbusiness-env.nun6xjgzft.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/webapi/item/ENP0723130912RZ

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(http://palmbusiness-env.nun6xjgzft.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/webapi/item/ENP0723130912RZ)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        if (response.isSuccessful())
            return response.body().string();

    } catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

expecting a common JSON response from across all networks.

Comment: Sorry for a counter-question, What if I write a script and send thousands of request onto your Beanstalk URL mentioned in the question? Will it prevent Denial Service automatically or you need to prevent it?

Comment: `function like GET not working properly (It fetches data but not the very updated data).` what do you mean by this?

Comment: If i modified the "Item" the updated content won't be fetched but the previous content use to be fetched.